# show servlet's response.getWriter().println() before servlet's ends

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

first of all I want to say that I am new in html/jsp/java/servlets, etc... and thanks to this forum i managed to get my first webapp working.  But now I am having a problem and i couldnt find a solution on the site.
The problem is that I call a servlet from a jsp, this servlet deploys different applications and I simply want to show the println that I call in the servlet before de servlet ends, right now, even If I have 10 println in different moments of the deploy process, the server only shows them when the servlets ends processing, which doesnt hace much sense for my app because i am trying to show the different steps of the deploy.
The servlet code is something like this:

```
public class Deploys extends HttpServlet {
String HOME = System.getenv("TRACE_HOME");
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    String broker = req.getParameter("Broker");
    String eg = req.getParameter("Eg");
    String servicio = req.getParameter("cboServicios");
    String bar = req.getParameter("cboBarFiles");

    // deploy 
    BrokerProxy b;
    try {
        out.println("connecting to server");
        b = utils.connect("LOCALQM");
        out.println("connect succesfull");
        ExecutionGroupProxy e = b.getExecutionGroupByName(eg);
        String path = HOME + "\\deploys\\files\\" + servicio + "\\"; 
        DeployResult dr = e.deploy(path + bar,true, 60000);
        out.println("Deployment completion code = "+dr.getCompletionCode()); 
    } catch (ConfigManagerProxyLoggedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ConfigManagerProxyPropertyNotInitializedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

and the server shows this all at the same time
connecting to server
connect succesfull
starting deploy
deploy completed

I read that the way to to this is using ajax an jquetr but I couldnt find an example of how to do it, so if any one can help will be very appreciated

Comment: Could it work using flush(); ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because it only does everything when the servlet is fully deployed, so it will do everything on the servlet almost instantly. At least that's how I learned it.

I think you could only do it editing the server or something like that. I don't think it's possible to do it on jQuery or ajax because the servlet would already be deployed. What you can do, however, is to do those outputs at servlet execution, so it prints while it's processing the code.

Comment: "What you can do, however, is to do those outputs at servlet execution, so it prints while it's processing the code." you mean like a System.out.println() to write in console? what I need is the outputs to be shown on the jsp

Comment: No, you can write in JSP from the servlet. Could you post the complete servlet code, it could help a lot.

Comment: I don't think it is possible: it will deploy everything pretty much fast, so it will only print everything instantly. But good luck on your search, if you read that it's possible, maybe it has a way of doing it.

EDIT: You could use a Thread.sleep between the lines of code to pause it a little and then continue it, so it simulates a little delay... It's not that good, but it's something.

Comment: the deploy takes about a minute, so is not as fast as you think, and the problem is that for this minute the pages doesnt show anything, so it looks like is not doing anything

Comment: Well then, I think that's server-related, not related to the way you code the JSP or your Servlet, I have to research it a little more, because there's nothing like your question in the internet (at least I didn't find anything like it)...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution, I am not sure if its the best way to do it or if it is just a workaround, but it works!
I used flush() and the most important is that I had to set the response type in the servlet.
This is how my "hello world" servlet used to test this case finally works.

```
public class HolaMundo extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/css");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World! entrada");
    out.flush();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.println("Hello World! salida");
    out.flush();
}
```

}